# Vue-cli version 3 BETA webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am trying to learn and test the upcoming version of vuejs/vue-cli ( beta 3.0 ) which will be a big step toward an easiest webpack configuration.
In the meantime, there is few examples....

As a test I tried to go from the vue-cli v2

**webpack.dev.conf.js**

```
plugins: [
    //...
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
            to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
            ignore: ['.*']
        }
    ]) ]
```

to the new vue-cli version 3 ( beta)

**vue.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('copy')
            .use(require('copy-webpack-plugin')), [{
                from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
                to: 'static', ignore: ['.*']
            }]
    }
}
```

running

```
npm run serve
```

does not complains...

so it seems to be OK, but I would like to know if there are some papers , tuts , examples already existing on this topic...  fr the time being I only discover new features by reading existing code source

Currently I am struggling in converting this :

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}),
```

I tried .

```
config
  .plugin('provide')
  .use(require('webpack.ProvidePlugin')), [{
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  }]
```

but I get an error :

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'webpack.ProvidePlugin'
 Error: Cannot find module 'webpack.ProvidePlugin'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
```

Comment: This section of the vue-cli docs (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/webpack.md) is the only one on webpack configuration I know so far. Anyway, what is the actual problem you have?

Comment: thanks for your feedback...  I updated my question with the current issue  I ahve...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your require command is wrong/unecessary, nothing to do with webpack or vue-cli

Example code:

```
config
  .plugin('provide')
  .use(require('webpack').ProvidePlugin, [{
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  }])
```

Comment: thanks ... did not catch up with the require()
however running i , I get  an error
 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  TypeError: Plugin is not a constructor
TypeError: Plugin is not a constructor

Comment: Oh, it's ProvidePlugin, no providePlugin. Will correct my answer,

Comment: Using the latest vue-cli version (3.2.1) and trying to use jquery, I found that the plugin rather expects an array like in oniondomes' answer

Comment: Yeah I was wrong here, fixed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

This should work unless you don't use webpack v4 (v4 throws an error for some reason):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('provide')
            .use(webpack.ProvidePlugin, [{
                $: 'jquery',
                jquery: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
            }]);
    },
};
```

[This](https://github.com/mozilla-neutrino/webpack-chain#getting-started) (found in the documentation I shared with you in the comment section) is probably something you want to get familiar with if you want to make some changes to `vue-cli` configuration.

Note: you have to use an array passing parameters to the plugin. Although the plugin itself expects an Object, `use()` is waiting for an array of arguments. That's why you should use array instead.

Answer (score 3):

I should define the new plugin usage before ...

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a project generated using the latest Vue CLI verstion ATM (3.2.1), I found that configuring jQuery required adding a Webpack Plugin to the project.

This is successfully done in the `vue.config.js` with the following syntax that uses both top answers:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin("provide").use(require("webpack").ProvidePlugin, [
      {
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
      }
    ]);
  }
};
```

This avoids installing `webpack` and passes an array of objects to the `config.plugin` function rather than an object.