# Add Jquery to Vue-Cli 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm currently trying to add Jquery to my `vue-cli` project. I am aware of the missbehaviour it can produce, but anyway; Since there is no `build/webpack.base.conf.js` anymore I tried editing `vue.config.js` by adding:

```
 module.exports {
    ...
    chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('define').tap(definitions => {
      definitions[0] = Object.assign(definitions[0], {
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        _: 'lodash'
      })
      return definitions
    })
  }
   ...
 }
```

or

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports {
   ...
 plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
     jquery: 'jquery',
     'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery'
   })
  ]
   ...
 }
```

Both options don't seem to work. With #1 nothing seems to happen, with #2 I get the compile error; "plugins" is not allowed or 'ProvidePlugin' is unresolved and
when I try to import jQuery directly in main.js and define the $ operator, jquery stays undefinded when I try to use it.

Big thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49626085/3233827)?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I already tried that. Didn't seem to work for me but I will try it again and maybe this post will help some more when enhanced.

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat if you found the answer - please add an answer under the question (and not inside the question itself).

Comment: @Dekel Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You can now accept the answer :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Solved it** by adding to `main.js`

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

That did it for me and jQuery is now available *globally*.

Another approach would be;

```
Vue.use({
install: function(Vue, options){
    Vue.prototype.$jQuery = require('jquery'); // you'll have this.$jQuery anywhere in your vue project
    }
});
```

I hope this will help someone stumbling over the same problem in the future. If you still can't figure it out, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49626085/3233827) or have a look at [the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html).

**edit:** make sure you ran `npm install jquery`.

Comment: remembering that is necessary to have Jquery module available in npm, you can do it doing: `npm install jquery`

Comment: Nowadays I would consider this as bad advice. As Vue is highly reactive, Jquery may change application state without lettings Vue know about the new state. This may cause inconsistent state-changes.
Use causiously :)
See https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 18):

#2 You forget to add *configureWebpack* into vue.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I did it by following steps:

first install jquery

```
npm install jquery --save-dev
```

in any component or view:

```
<script>

import jQuery from "jquery";
const $ = jQuery;
window.$ = $;

....
....
....
```

or as above answer, both are same:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

now you can use anywhere in the page, for globally availability, simply follow the above said answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in vue.config.js

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  config
    .plugin('provide')
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    .use(require('webpack').ProvidePlugin, [{
      'window.Quill': 'quill/dist/quill.js',
      Quill: 'quill/dist/quill.js',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery/src/jquery.js',
      jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery.js',
    }]);
},
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.