# Using jquery ui and time picker with vue

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am trying to setup vue cli with jquery ui, but couldn't figure out how to use jquery ui components. I need to load following js files

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js
```

and 
css files

```
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css
```

To make the timepicker work. Here is a codepen link where I have tested the functionality.
https://codepen.io/cksachdev/pen/EJgGVR

Any suggestions on how should I go about loading these using vue-cli/ webpack configuration.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'jquery-ui': '../../../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets',
      'jquery-ui-css': '../../../node_modules/jquery-ui/../../themes/base',
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

---

***Edit 2:*** I went ahead and wrote a demo project that you can mirror to accomplish this..

***[View the demo here](http://vue-jquery-timepicker.ostrike.com)***

***[View the source code/repo here](https://github.com/oze4/vue-jQuery-timepicker)***

Again, not sure why you would want to do this, but ^that^ is (another) solution..

---

---

---

You can add those scripts and css files inside the 'index.html' file (public -> index.html), and use it like this:

***Edit 1:*** it is extremely important to note there is no reason you need to import (the rather large) jQuery or even use jQuery. The Vue ecosystem has plenty of existing options for things like this..

[vue2-timepicker](https://phoenixwong.github.io/vue2-timepicker/) and [Vuetify timepicker](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers#examples) (Vuetify is more of a full library of pre-styled components)..

[image: Edit Vue/jQuery Time Picker]

[[CodePen mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/mgLjXp?editors=1010)]

```js
/* TIMEPICKER COMPONENT */
const VueTimepicker = {
  template: "#vue-timepicker",
  computed: {
    id() {
      // give the component a unique id/name
      return "time-picker-" + this._uid;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $("#" + this.id).timepicker({
      timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss:l"
    });
  }
};

/* VUE APP */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    VueTimepicker,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" />

<!-- ******************** -->
<!-- VUE APP -->
<!-- ******************** -->
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Timepicker 1</span>
      <vue-timepicker/>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <span>Timepicker 2</span>
      <vue-timepicker/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ******************** -->
<!-- TIMEPICKER COMPONENT -->
<!-- ******************** -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="vue-timepicker">
  <div>
    <input type="text" :name="id" :id="id" value=" ">
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for a webpack based solution using vue-cli.

Comment: This will work with webpack and vue-cli. That's what CodeSandbox uses. Do you mean you want to use jQuery as a module versus importing in index.html?

Comment: Yes, I want to import jQuery and jQuery ui using webpack. Below is what I have tried, but it fails on loading jQuery ui images. I have tried to add alias, that didn't worked and tried copy pasting the images folder manually too, but no luck.
Can't paste here, updating in main question.

Comment: I tried https://codesandbox.io/s/o96mp85m86?fontsize=14 link, and I can't see timepicker working.

Comment: Try again.. I was testing using as modules but have reverted changes. It is working now.

Comment: @ChetanSachdev you can do this, but it is rather convoluted. It's easiest to import them via CDN (in index.html).. [Use jQuery via NPM in vue-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355086/add-jquery-to-vue-cli-3) and how to [use jQuery UI as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module) - note: you have to extend the vue-cli webpack config via [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config).. Overall, just easier to use jQuery via CDN (although, you don't even need jQuery when using Vue.. kind of an anti-pattern)

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I am trying to achieve. Don't want manual script and link tags in html file. I don't have any html file now.

Comment: @ChetanSachdev I went ahead and wrote a demo for you.  Please see my updated answer - provides a demo site, as well as the GitHub repo that I am storing the source code at.