# Using JQuery globally in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am simply trying to import JQuery to use globally in my Vue 3 application, but I am getting the error the `window.$ is not a function`.

I have followed this other article: [Add Jquery to Vue-Cli 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355086/add-jquery-to-vue-cli-3)

I have defined JQuery in my main.js like this:

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

JQuery is installed via npm and this works fine. However, whenever I try to use `window.$` in any of my components (under the script tag in my .vue files) I get the error that `window.$ is not a function`.

How have I managed to mess this up?

Comment: Hi, well this is only a suggestion, a personal suggestion as Vue developer with a few years of experience, you don't need JQuery inside a Vue project, Vue provides a lot of benefits, so I really recommend to not use JQuery. If you really want to do it, maybe you can register it as a plugin in the main.js file.

Comment: I wanted to use bootstraps popover feature, for which you need JQuery. Can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: Are you sure that JQuery is doing something that can't be replaced with VanillaJS?, I only can see events and a document selector in the documentation

Check this https://therichpost.com/vue-3-bootstrap-5-popover-working-demo/

Comment: @m.tracey Perhaps https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/

Comment: @m.tracey I read your comments and updated the answer according to your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I read your comments and understood what you actualy need. This answer is based on what you actual need but not what you want to do. I believe this method is better
Use Boostrap 5 which is not jQuery dependent, you can use all the features like dropdowns, popups without jQuery.
in your main.js import the following after installing boostarp via `npm install bootstrap`

```
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' //boostarp
```

install `npm install bootstrap` as you will have to include them as I have shown above. as per [Bootstrap Doc.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/#package-managers)

**NB:** Vue3 does not support boostarp 4, and vue-boostrap use boostrap 5 instead

Comment: so bootstrap 5 is compatible with vue 3 but bootstrap 4 is not? I didn’t know bootstrap 5 wasn’t jquery dependent so that’s great news to me! I’m facing the same issue with a project that relies pretty heavily on bootstrap and subsequently jquery. We’re on bootstrap 4 so my upgrade to vue 3 is not going well lol. Vue-bootstrap is also not compatible with vue3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working For my Vue 3 and Nuxt-bridge app. I made sure I didn't have any versions of bootstrap, popper or jquery in my package.json

I added this to the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
script: [
      {
        src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        type: "text/javascript"
      },
      {
        src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
        integrity: "sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ",
        crossorigin:"anonymous"

      }
]
```